# Elementer trigger popup close/open depend on which Swiper slide is active

Tags: swiper.js, elementor

I writing a code that trigger open an Elementor popup when some Swiper slide is active, close the popup when the slide is not active.

```
<script>
function FirstSwiperSlide()
{
    jQuery
    (
        function($)
        {
            // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
            let targetNode = $('.swiper-pagination-bullets > span:nth-child(1)');

            // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
            const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false, attributeFilter: ['class'] };

            // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
            const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
                for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
                    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
                        var classList = mutation.target.className;
                        // Do something here with class you're expecting
                        if(classList.includes('swiper-pagination-bullet-active'))
                        {
                            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: 3266 } ); // Not working!
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 3266 } ); // Working!
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
            const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

            // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
            observer.observe(targetNode[0], config);

            // Later, you can stop observing
            //observer.disconnect();
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

The problem is in the `elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: 3266 } );` code that returns an error:

> elements-handlers.min.js?ver=3.18.2:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of **undefined (reading 'target')**
> at _default.closePopup (elements-handlers.min.js?ver=3.18.2:2:21411)
> at :1:36

So, as I understand, this function want some event parameter `elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: 3266 }, **event** );`

I have no idea which event need to put there.

I have tried to put click event to check if `elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: 3266 }, event );` is working, in this way its does not return error, but also not close the popup:

```
jQuery( document ).ready
( 
    function( $ )
    {
        $( document ).on( 'click', '.swiper-pagination-bullet:not(.swiper-pagination-bullet-active)', 
        function( event )
        {
            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: 3266 }, event );
            console.log("pass");
        } );
    } 
);
```

Dont know how to expect from this code `elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: 3266 });` to work, any solution?